# What is the worst case for KMP string search algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, testing, complexity-theory

Can anyone suggest me a worst case "text string - pattern pair" for testing a KMP algorithm implementation?

Comment: KMP has linear runtime complexity, so any string with the target at the end will run in worst-case time. And id your implementation is a multifind then every case runs in linear time.

Comment: I'll write my answer here since the question is closed: in their paper "Fast pattern matching in string" Knuth, Morris and Pratt prove that the worst case for the algorithm are the Fibonacci strings defined as 
$ \phi_1 = b, \phi_2 = b, \phi_n= \phi_{n-1}\phi_{n-2} $ Check section 5. Theoretical considerations of the paper.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say a pattern like

```
xx........x
| n times |
```

and a string like

```
xxx.........xyx...........xy....
| n-1 times | | n-1 times |
```

would be one of the worst cases, but it's still `O(m+n)`

Comment: Whenever a mismatch occurs we keep shifting pattern character pointer to left according to prefix-suffix matching table. For the example in your answer at every y character we find a mismatch and we keep shifting the character pointer of the pattern 1 character left at a time. If there are c1 no of x characters and c2 no of y character in the text the total no of comparison we get is ( c1+ c2 *pattern size). Am I right?

Comment: @FarsanRashid I've been practicing algo/DS and searched for KMP worst case. After reading this answer, the same thing came into my mind that you wrote above.. and surprise, I know this guy xD

Answer (score 2):

You can find anything on KMP algorithm here :

[KMP ALGORITHM](http://www.personal.kent.edu/%7Ermuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/StringMatch/kuthMP.htm)

> **Quick extract :**
>
> Knuth, Morris and Pratt discovered first linear time string-matching
> algorithm by following a tight analysis of the naïve algorithm.
> Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm keeps the information that naïve approach
> wasted gathered during the scan of the text. By avoiding this waste of
> information, it achieves a running time of O(n + m), which is optimal
> in the worst case sense. **That is, in the worst case Knuth-Morris-Pratt
> algorithm we have to examine all the characters in the text and
> pattern at least once.**

You should be able to calrify what you understand of the algorithm and find what you need there.

hope it helps